# Manga with someone who became a reincarnated as a baron son and is sent to a military facility

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

I don't really remember the whole summary or genre but it's about this guy who is from another world and who reincarnates into a baron's son. The baron's son wasn't the oldest son, so he got sent to a military facility and someone than reincarnated into his body. He was good at torturing people.

I read this on Mangadex. I know it's not *Tyranny of Steel*. It did not have any harem, ecchi, kingdom building, or conquering in it.

Comment: Not a manga, but a light novel; https://m.webnovel.com/book/tyranny-of-steel_20627562705133205

Comment: Nay, I read the manga like 4 months ago on mangadex.org but I can't find it anymore 'cause  don't remember the title. And It's not the "tyranny of steel" the manga doesn't have 'harem, ecchi, kingdombuilding, or conquer." in it.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site, it looks like you've got some good details but please do [edit] some more in if the advice [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) reminds you of anything else you could add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might this be ***[When I Reincarnated I Was a Soldier?! - A Man Called the Red Shinigami](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=176589)***...?

From Baka-Updates:

> A soldier from a different world with the memory of being Japanese. After getting beaten by an orc club, he regains his memory of his previous life and survives the world of war despite the confusion.
>
> Leverage your lack of presence. Let’s shake off the unfavorable things of the previous life and this world.
>
> From the third son of the Baron family to a high-ranking aristocrat. Light territory management and special pets. The protagonist is not the strongest.
>
> Magic exists, but the protagonist cannot use it. It is a world where God exists. There is also gore.

The main character describes himself as a "former Japanese" reincarnated as Patrick "Patt" Rigsby, the third son of a baronial family. In this world, 15-year-olds are considered adults, and he joined the Royal Army as soon as he came of age.

He's also shown to have tortured a man to extract information from him.

[image]

[image]

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!YES. >----<